# C# .net OWIN - starting a route for a WebAPI with a Wildcard dynamic URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, owin

I have a WebApi hosted in OWIN and I was wondering if it was possible to have the beginning of the URL a "wildcard", so for example if I have a WebAPI named "GetUsers", a person accessing my WebAPI would be able to type:

```
http://localhost/blah-blah-blah/api/GetUsers

http://localhost/api/GetUsers

http://localhost/ABC/api/GetUsers
```

and all routes would take him to GetUsers. Is this possible? I tried stuff like adding `[Route("{*uri}/api/GetUsers")]` to the function but it doesn't seem to work, tried the same in WebAPIConfig ->

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerAndAction", 
    routeTemplate: "{*uri}/api/{controller}/{action}"
);
```

but that didn't work as well.

Is there any way to create a WebAPI with a "wildcard starting URL", or is it impossible?

Comment: Do not use the `*` it will cause conflicts. `{prefix}/api/{controller}/{action}` should work for your 1st and 3rd option. Optional placeholers are not allowed in the middle of route templates so you would have to register the `api/{controller}/{action}` separately.

Comment: This worked really well, thanks! If you want, you can submit this as an answer to the question so I can flag the question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the `*` in your proposed route template. It will cause conflicts. `{prefix}/api/{controller}/{action}` should work for your 1st and 3rd option. Optional placeholders are not allowed in the middle of route templates so you would have to register the `api/{controller}/{action}` separately.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "PrefixedControllerAndAction", 
    routeTemplate: "{prefix}/api/{controller}/{action}"
); 

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerAndAction", 
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
);
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to have 2 prefixes for the Http route? It seems something like {prefix}/{prefix}/api/{controller}/{action} does not work.

Comment: Just do something like {prefix1}/{prefix2}/api/{controller}/{action}

Answer (score 1):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerAndAction", 
    routeTemplate: "{*uri}/api/{controller}/{action}"
);
```